# props does not exist on type PropType

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a prop ("author") which is passed from a parent component. I have typed the propType("AuthorProps") but it say `Property 'author' does not exist on type 'AuthorProps'` even though the structure look same.

AuthorProps:

```
export type AuthorProps = {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  authorId:string;
  img: string;
  createdAt?: string;
  updatedAt?: string;
  __v?: number;
}
```

author props logged:

```
{
    _id: "61ffff139d0ad2a68738843a",
    name: "Chetan Bagat",
    slug: "chetan-bagat",
    authorId: "0",
    img: "https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-66099431,width-650,imgsize-149367,,resizemode-4,quality-100/chetan-bhagats-advice-for-students-its-all-about-knowing-how-to-market-yourself.jpg",
    createdAt: "2022-02-06T17:02:11.490Z",
    updatedAt: "2022-02-06T17:02:11.490Z",
    __v: 0
}
```

Component:

```
function AuthorContainer({ author }: AuthorProps) { // }
```

Comment: You seem to have `authorId`, but not `author`?

Comment: @Yes, You could see the author object above.

Comment: Replace `{ author }: AuthorProps` with `{ author }: { author: AuthorProps }`.

Comment: @iz_ Thanks,That worked! But what was the issue with my way? We normally use it that way right ?

Comment: `{ author }: AuthorProps` means that `{ author }` is of type `AuthorProps`, but it isn't. The shape of your props is `{ author: AuthorProps }` or `{ author: { _id: string; name: string; ... } }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component, you use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and try to get `{author}` from `AuthorProps`. The definition of `AuthorProps` does not contain this property.

Probably, you want to change your code to something like this:

```
export type AuthorProps = {
  author: {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    slug: string;
    authorId:string;
    img: string;
    createdAt?: string;
    updatedAt?: string;
    __v?: number;
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it thanks! ..

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the type, this is recommended.

```
function AuthorContainer(author: AuthorProps) { // }
```